# AngularJS call webmethod

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS and I've set it up with an mvc application.
I'm trying to convert a small piece of code that was written before in JQuery to AngularJS but can't figure out how to get it working. The problem is that I don't know how to call a codebehind method in my controller with AngularJS ?

This is how it is working now in JQuery:

```
//JQuery calling code behind
$(document).on("click", ".open-AppDescriptionDialog", function () {
    var title = "Title";
    var state = "active";

    //call method
    $.post('<%= Url.Action("StatusInfoString") %>', { header: title, status: state }, ParseResult);
});



//method in controller
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult StatusInfoString(string path, string status)
{
     ServiceClient serviceClient = new ServiceClient();
     var data = serviceClient.GetResults();

     return Content(data);
 }
```

Anyone an idea how this is done ?

Comment: look at `$http` service in angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In angular their are different way to achieve this and angular has module for the same

Below is the list

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$httpBackend

You need to inject this module from above, generally people write service for this using factory mehthod below is the example:

```
app.factory('myService', function($http) {
   return {
     getList:function(params){
          var promise= $http({url: 'ServerURL',method: "POST", params: params}).then(function(response,status){

            return response.data;
            });
          // Return the promise to the controller
          return promise; 
        }
   }
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
  myService.getList(function(data) {
     $scope.foo = data;
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new to AngularJS. How would I go and actually implement this? Can you link to some small example?

Comment: Hi, I'm getting 'myService is undefined'. How do I create 'myService' ?

Comment: Hi check the working example @ http://plnkr.co/edit/3Eoq0zmv5NnOpHvyccaS?p=preview