# $http request with angularjs is returning my html doc

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I'm new here, so sorry if I'm making some mistake with the post...

I'm trying to use angularjs with ASP.NET Web Forms, and everything was going well until I need to make a request to the c# webmethods. I searched here and on other pages for the solution and didnt found anything.

Let's go to te problem: My request just return my Default.aspx html code, and not my JSON. In fact, my request doesn't call my webmethod...

```
app.controller('CtrlBoletos',function($scope, FactoryBoleto) {

    $scope.selections = [];

    $scope.boletos =  FactoryBoleto.getBoletos();

    $scope.gridBoletos = {
        data: 'boletos',
        selectedItems: $scope.selections,
        multiSelect: false
    };
});


app.factory('FactoryBoleto', function ($http) {

   var getBoletos = function() {

        $http({
           method: 'POST',
           url: "./Default.aspx/get_boleto",
           async: false
        }).success(function(result){
           console.info(result);
        });
   };
   return { getBoletos: getBoletos };
});
```

and this is my webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
 public static string get_boleto()
{     
    List<TFechamento_Boleto> lista = new List<TFechamento_Boleto>();
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer =new JavaScriptSerializer();
    TFechamento fechamento = new TFechamento(2);
    lista = fechamento.getDados(1).Boleto;

    var json = serializer.Serialize(lista);
    return json;

}
```

Ah, and if i make the request with JQuery AJAX I get the json...

someone help me, im getting crazy with this... and sorry for my bad english :p

Comment: Side note: there is a Portuguese version of stack here: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: You can use the Developer Tool (F12) in your browser (Chrome, IE or Firefox) and inspect the two requests to see what you're missing, as you said it can be request using jQuery.

Comment: I did that, the requests are the same, i used firebug to see them... already changed the header from the $http request, make them equal and dont worked...... @SergioGarcia

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved this issue by setting headers, responseType and by adding an empty data object

```
factory.handshake = function () {
    return $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: urlBase.concat("/Handshake"),
        data: {},
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        responseType: 'json'
    });
};
```

...and, when I call my webmethod the result magically appears

```
    myFactory.handshake()
        .success(function (fromApi) {
            alert(fromApi.d);
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load sport data: ' + error.message;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)] ?

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public List<ProjectOfEmployee> GetAllProjectName()
{
   return GetProjectName();   
}
```

http://shahjadatalukdar.wordpress.com/2013/08/09/how-to-call-asmx-webservice-using-http-get-
with-jquery-ajax/

Checking, some others threads:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/AQ_caU-qVJ0/Csugs6zI2-EJ

[AngularJS call webmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053552/angularjs-call-webmethod)

Comment: Didn't work, the result of request is the html page yet... :(

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem as you.until now i have create an alternative solution to get json result from my c# webmethod:

```
 $scope.yourscopefunction=function(){
         $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "webmethodURL",                       
                        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {

                            $.map(data.d, function (dataobject) {

                              alert(dataobject.yourobjectfield);

                            });

                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {

                            alert(status + "* " + errorThrown + " * " + xhr);
                        }
                    });

 };
```

if you have an other solution better than this using $http, please tell me

Answer (score 0):

I tinkered with this out of curiosity/learning Angular:

The issue is `content-type` header - [if you don't define this, the WebMethod isn't invoked](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks) and you will get the `aspx` page (in both jQuery and Angular..any actually)

> ASP.NET AJAX Content-Type Header Validation
>
> There is a built-in validation layer of protection that ASP.NET enforces for both GET and POST based ASP.NET AJAX web methods, which is that regardless of the HTTP verb being used, **ASP.NET always requires that the HTTP Content-Type header is set** to the value **application/json**. *If this content type header is not sent, ASP.NET AJAX will reject the request on the server.*

So try this, not really sending any data, but Angular will set the header:

```
$http.post("default.aspx/get_boleto", {});
```

or in your case:

```
 $http({
       method: 'POST',
       url: "./Default.aspx/get_boleto",
       data: {}, //nothing really, just doing this so the header is set
       async: false
    }).success(.....
```

If you inspect your XHR call:

Angular XHR **without** data, `Content-Type` **isn't** set:

```
POST /default.aspx/helloWorld HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:51120
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:51120
User-Agent: ....
Referer: ....
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Angular XHR **with** data, `Content-Type` **is** set:

```
POST /default.aspx/helloWorld HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:51120
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:51120
User-Agent:...
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: ....
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

New at Angular so if there are better/easier ways, I'll defer...

Hth...